# Python Get Value of Javascript Variable

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm **scraping** instagram page (https://instagram.com/celmirashop) and get script (HTML and some javascript). the result like this

```
<script>some script</script>
<script>some script</script>
<script>some script</script>
<script>window._sharedData = {"config":{"csrf_token":"sSqrj6c8tfN1HwOIlwmpqONT2bAPhtNu","viewer":null etc....</script>
```

I have creating script like this

```
import urllib.request
import json
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

web = urllib.request.urlopen("https://instagram.com/celmirashop")
soup = BeautifulSoup(web.read(), 'lxml')
pattern = re.compile(r"window._sharedData = .")
script = soup.find("script",text=pattern)
print(script)
```

and giving me a result a specific javascript that I want to. like this

```
<script>window._sharedData = {"config":{"csrf_token":"sSqrj6c8tfN1HwOIlwmpqONT2bAPhtNu","viewer":null etc....</script>
```

How can I get the value of window._sharedData ? and loop it. because I want save in mysql

Answer (score 2):

Assuming ends with ; and occurs only once you can use the following regex pattern on the response.text

```
import re

s = '''<script>window._sharedData = {"config":{"csrf_token":"sSqrj6c8tfN1HwOIlwmpqONT2bAPhtNu","viewer":null"};</script>'''
p = re.compile(r'window\._sharedData = (.*);')
print(p.findall(s)[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way:

```
>>> xxx = '''
... <script>window._sharedData = {"config":{"csrf_token":"sSqrj6c8tfN1HwOIlwmpqONT2bAPhtNu","viewer":null etc....</script>
... '''
```

```
>>> xxx.split('"csrf_token":"')
['\n<script>window._sharedData = {"config":{', 'sSqrj6c8tfN1HwOIlwmpqONT2bAPhtNu","viewer":null etc....</script>\n']

>>> xxx.split('"csrf_token":"')[1].split('"')[0]
'sSqrj6c8tfN1HwOIlwmpqONT2bAPhtNu'
```

Just note that BS, doesn't actually run any javascript, so the script tags, or any other javascript isn't actually being run.

You'll have to use something like selenium in order to do something more with it.

If you do go with selenium you can, do something like:

```
import json
import selenium.webdriver

options = selenium.webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)

driver.get('https://instagram.com/celmirashop')

# note this assumes there is no circular data, etc in the thing 
# passed to`JSON.stringify`

# run this javascript in the firefox browser
js = "return JSON.stringify(window._sharedData)"

# load the hopefully stringified json to python 
hello = json.loads(driver.execute_script(js))

for k, v in hello.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Comment: _return JSON.stringify(window._sharedData)_ nice +